# Sending authorised GoogleApiClient to a service

Tags: google-drive-api

I have an android application where Im uploading a file to Google Drive. First I load an activity and let a user make some choises, then I start an service that uploads the file in the background. As I understand I need to create the GoogleApiClient in an activity to be able to launch the authorization screens. How Im i supposed to get the then authorised GoogleApiClient to my background service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can instantiate the GoogleApiClient in the Activity once in order to ensure that the user has selected an account and authorized your app.  Once they have done that once, they shouldn't need to do it again.

At that point you can create a new GoogleApiClient in your service and be fairly confident it will succeed.  If it fails, you could always throw up a notification or some such indicating the user needs to take action.

That said, you shouldn't need a background service just to write a file.  Since the actual upload will happen in the background already, all you need to do is write to the Contents in an AsyncTask.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that the resolution for a failed connect attempt is a PendingIntent.  PendingIntents are Parcelable and can be sent from your service back to your client, or to a notification, where the user can handle it.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem...

I solve it by making part of my configuration activity the login to google (check if google play is installed, register and then connect).  The activity asks for my google account and password.

My service then don't have problems with connect.  I also find that I only have to supply my google login and password once.  When I restart my app and I start the configuration activity, it connect to the drive SDK without asking my google login and password

Comment: You should never ask for your user's password.  This is very insecure.